# Did I overfill my diesel engine with oil?

Tags: engine, oil, turbocharger

I put 5L of the correct oil in my diesel car when I noticed it was low. I then had a lot of white smoke coming out of my car: have I damaged my turbo?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe you put exactly the right amount in and the white smoke is unrelated. More details would certainly help us help you. Whatever you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Which make and model is this? Where was the smoke coming from?

Comment: Did you check the dipstick after you filled up, i.e. are you sure you overfilled?

Comment: I'm voting to close, not because the question is unclear, but because the details around it are and the OP isn't responding to comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have put 5L of engine oil on top of an oil level that was just showing low on the dipstick & needed topping up, then yes you've overfilled it and shouldn't use the vehicle until you have drained off the excess oil. Otherwise the excess oil will create crankcase back pressure which can lead to all sorts of issues including the one you mention as the very high oil level/pressure forces its way into areas is shouldn't necessarily be.

Drain the excess off and check for any problems.. If you are lucky the white smoke may just be from oil blowing past the piston rings which will take a little while to burn off. If the smoke doesn't clear up then further investigation will be required into what has been damaged by the excess pressure.